# preprocessor directive to increase stack size not working

Tags: c++, stack, preprocessor-directive

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <ctime> 
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

void showArray(int data[], int n);
int partition(int data[], int low, int high);
void quicksort(int data[], int low, int high);
void sort(int data[], int n);

int comparisonCount;
int sortCount;

#pragma comment(linker, "/STACK: 8000000")


int main()
{
srand((unsigned)time(0));
int random_integer;
int lowest = 1, highest = 1000;
int range = (highest - lowest) + 1;
int arrayList[1000];


for (int i = 0; i < highest; i++) {
    random_integer = lowest + int(range*rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0));
    arrayList[i] = random_integer;
}


sort(arrayList, highest);
showArray(arrayList, highest);


}
```

Whenever I try to run this I get the error...`invalid directive '8000000' found; does not start with '/'`

The unseen parts of this code will involve a lot of recursion so the stack size needs to be increased. I don't know why that director isn't working.

Comment: Remove space. It is obvious, isn't it?

Comment: I see. That code was copied and pasted from the professor's document so I assumed it was correct.

Comment: @Jason there is no substitute for [reading the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/linker-options) when things don't work as you expect

Answer (score 2):

The linker option shouldn't have any spaces in it.

```cpp
#pragma comment(linker, "/STACK:8000000")
//                              ^ no space here
```